# Select rows in Pandas dataframe with empty lists in specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                                        parte_passiva       name
0                                                  []       Charles     
1              [INDUSTRIAS MENTEN DE CARTONAGEM LTDA]       Carlos      
2                 [MABE BRASIL ELETRODOMÉSTICOS LTDA]       Mark
3                            [ACUMULADORES AJAX LTDA]       Marcos        
...
```

Note that the 'parte_passiva' column is made of lists.
I want to select those rows that have an empty list, so I'm trying:

```
df2=df1.loc[(df1['parte_passiva'] == [])]
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
 ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 60 vs 0
```

Any ideas how to surpass this stage?

Comment: Check using string length == 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select them via `str.len`

```
df2=df1.loc[(df1['parte_passiva'].str.len() == 0),:]
```

Or using

```
df1[~df1.parte_passiva.astype(bool)]
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. Question: if I want to add an OR inside that `.loc`, like `df1.loc[((df1['parte_passiva'].str.len() == 0),:) | ((df1['parte_ativa'].str.len() == 0),:)]` what would be the right synthax?

Comment: @abutremutante like this `df1.loc[(df1['some1'].str.len() == 0) | (df1['some2'].str.len() == 0),:]`